# How don't see previous ViewControllers during unwind for "Present Modally"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, presentmodalviewcontroller

I want to create three view controllers: A -> B -> C -> A

"B" and "C" controllers have to be transparent, so I create "Present Modally" segue. From "C" I created unwind segue to "A"

But when I return from "C" to "A" I also see how "B" is closing.

What to do? This is my storyboard:

[image: 3 view controllers, first leading to second, second leading to third]

View controllers have only this functions:

```
// DraftAViewController
    @IBAction func goToBTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToB", sender: self)
    }
    
    @IBAction func unwind( _ seg: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

// DraftBViewController
    @IBAction func goToCTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToC", sender: self)
    }

// DraftCViewController
    @IBAction func backToATapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToA", sender: self)
    }
```

[image: Presenting view controllers and dismissing all of them]

Comment: Can you show a gif/video of what the current behavior is like?

Comment: Could you use a container view to host view controller B inside view controller C?

Comment: In `backToATapped` you are calling performSegue(unwindToA, sender *self*). Have you tried passing the instance of `DraftBViewController` instead of `self`? You'd need to have a way of accessing B from C, but that shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @aheze added gif